# Check if Binary Tree is a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I tried to write a code to check if a given binary tree is a BST or not. But my code does not pass all the test cases. It passes 6 out of 8 test cases. Why is it wrong/incomplete?

below is my code

```
public static boolean isBST(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return true;
    }

    boolean left = isBST(root.left);
    boolean right = isBST(root.right);

    boolean currentL = true, currentR = true;

    if (root.left != null) {
        currentL = root.left.data < root.data;
    }

    if (root.right != null) {
        currentR = root.right.data > root.data;
    }

    return left && right && currentL && currentR;
}
```

using recursion, I get boolean for left and right. Then I return the final value as the answer if all  left, right and current subtree is BST. Where is my code lacking? Is it because even if a subtree is BST, its left node might be bigger than some element of main tree that the subtree is part of?

Comment: If this is [LeetCode 98](https://leetcode.com/problems/validate-binary-search-tree/), there’s an option to add the failed test case to the set of unit tests you can see. You can’t use a debugger unless you pay for premium, but for simple code like this, you can use print statements to debug your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does your solution say about the following tree?

```
      --6--
     /     \
   -4-     -8-
  /   \   /   \
 2     7 5     9
```

The left and right nodes are both valid binary search trees, and 4 is less than 6 and 8 is greater than 6. But doing a BST traversal of this will never find 7 or 5.

You need to ensure that the max value in the left node is less than the root, and vice versa for the right node.

Comment: "You need to ensure that the max value in the left node is less than the root, and vice versa for the right node" - in other words: in-order traversal must produce monotonic sequence

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now understand why my code gives an error